I have a list of images in the UI on click of remove image i have to match the id of deleted image record id and i have to delete from the databaseLWC
I have a list of images in the UI on click of remove image i have to match the id of deleted image record id and i have to delete from the databaseLWC

removeImage(event) {
    let index = event.target.dataset.index;
    this.isImageShown = false;
    this.imageBlobData = '';
    this.fileName = '';
    this.contentType = '';
    let posItemdata = this.posItemListTobedisplayed;
    console.log('posItemdata',JSON.stringify(posItemdata))
    let posItemdetails = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < posItemdata.length; i++) {
      if (index == posItemdata[i].key) {
        console.log('posItemdata[i].key',posItemdata[i].key)
        console.log('index',index)
        posItemdata[i].posItemImageURL = '';
        posItemdata[i].Attachment_ID__c = '';
      }
      posItemdetails.push(posItemdata[i]);
    }
    this.posItemListTobedisplayed = posItemdetails;
    this.validatePosItem(index);
  }

I tried several ways but still i am not understanding what my problem is.
Please help me
Thanks in advance
